# How to reload a batch file with .qwv containing section access in QlikView Desktop?

Tags: credentials, qlikview

I execute "C:\Program Files\QlikView\qv.exe" /R "D:\QlikViewAdm\qlik_file.qvw" to launch the loader. It works when there is no section access. However, when I run a file with section access QV asks me for login and password. I can link the access to Windows user credentials, but it only works on my terminal.

Is there a way to point QV to a local file with credentials?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you are suggesting about passing extra credentials through the command line. You can set the user to use with credentials if you run the batch file through the windows scheduler. Also make sure that the account that is running the batch file is in the section access list

Comment: it is not possible to combine 
section access + cli reload + other user than actually logged in to windows
best solution is to remove section access or just give access to current account in section access

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using NTNAME in the section Access like so:

Section Access;
LOAD * INLINE [
ACCESS, USERID, PASSWORD,NTNAME
ADMIN, ADMIN, ADMIN , *
ADMIN, , , yourWindowsUserID
];

you can get yourWindowsUserID by using the OsUser() function (in QlikView).

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice is that the user churning is following the exponential function like the nuclear decay. Hence, t-test is useless (it assumes normal distribution).
Second, it is time to look at counts of users with 0,1,2.. events.
Third, just use Wilcoxon test if you compare the same cohort of users before and after. Otherwise, use Mann–Whitney U test. It is less stable than the tests on normally distributed values. However, it does the job whenever you cannot promise normality.

Spoiler: yes, it worked out. Cohort 1 and 2 were nearly indistinguishable, but cohort 3 and 1 yielded a difference at p < 0.001.